# WP Edit user custom fields update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, edit

So I have gotten so close but there has got to be a mistake here.
What I am doing is I have added 3 custom fields to the WP wooCommerce installation. I have added via hooks and woo templates to registration andmy account pages. I can successfully update as a user from their profile area/front end fine. 
What I am stuck on is having the edit user admin form update these fields. I can get the fields to show but they are just not updating.

Looking for thoughts and help. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

This is my code in my child theme functions.php - ADMIN EDIT USER

```
function sbb_custom_user_profile_fields($user) {
?>
<legend><h4>Reseller Info</h4></legend>
<table class="form-table">
<tr>
<th>
    <label for="ssb_reseller_tax_id"><?php _e('Resseller Tax ID'); ?></label>
</th>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="sbb_reseller_tax_id" id="sbb_reseller_tax_id" 
value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'reseller_tax_id', $user->ID 
) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
    <label for="sbb_title"><?php _e('Title'); ?></label>
</th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="sbb_title" id="sbb_title" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'title', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>
    <label for="sbb_fax"><?php _e('Fax'); ?></label>
</th>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="sbb_fax" id="sbb_fax" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'fax', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
update_user_meta( get_the_author_meta( $user->ID ), 'reseller_tax_id', htmlentities( $_POST[ 'reseller_tax_id' ] ) );
update_user_meta( get_the_author_meta( $user->ID ), 'fax', htmlentities( $_POST[ 'fax' ] ) );
update_user_meta( get_the_author_meta( $user->ID ), 'title', htmlentities( $_POST[ 'title' ] ) );
}

add_action('show_user_profile', 'sbb_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'sbb_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'sbb_custom_user_profile_fields' );
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue I see with the code you've posted is you're prefixing the input names. You may save a value with a meta key of `reseller_tax_id` but the input name is `sbb_reseller_tax_id`. It's the input name you need to use in `$_POST`.

`$_POST[ 'reseller_tax_id' ] )` would become `$_POST['sbb_reseller_tax_id'] )`

I'd suggest checking that the form has been submit and that you have a value for an input before attempting to save it. Simply viewing a page shouldn't have the effect of performing an update.

Comment: thank you Nathan - I will give it a go and let you know